# Javascript - What is the reason for implied globals?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, hoisting

I know that if I write a code like:

```
function func() {
    b = 0;
}
```

then, the variable `b` will be a global variable. I heard this is called **implied globals**.

My question is why `b` becomes a global variable?

Is this by any chance related to **hoisting**?

Comment: No hoisting, assigning a value to an undeclared variable makes that variable global. The declaration statement binds a variable to the scope, if there's no declaration statement, the global scope is used. This is by design. If you run the code in the strict mode, trying to create an implied global fires an error.

Comment: Unless declared as local with `var`, variables in js are implied to be global.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I want to know the reason why the variable becomes global.

Comment: Why? That is by design, you ask Brendan Eich for the reasons.

Comment: @yakkisyou because that variable is not scoped using `var`, `let` or `const`. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement

Comment: @Teemu I am asking about the internal process of doing so.